# clustering pixels to create a solid shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a script that detects the bottom of a cooking pot, given a picture from above at a slightly slanted angle. This is a tough task due to lighting, lack of edges, and the glare of the metal pot.

This is a sample image I am working with:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBHCl.jpg)

`img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')`

`gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

The bottom of the pot is visible, but hard to detect.

So far, I was able to produce this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dc7z.png)  using:

`th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)`

And this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irSsD.png) using:

`edges = cv2.Canny(img,30,60)`

The solution seems intuitive since in both images the base can be detected easily, but I am not able to figure out the implementation.

My intuition tells me that I should cluster white pixels starting from the center of the image, and line the border of the segmentation generated from the clustering. I am not quite sure about how to go about that. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The approach by clustering pixels is hopeless. The image is too complex/cluttered.

Comment: "in both images the base can be detected easily": no ! This is an awfully difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

WORK IN PROGRESS

What is your overall goal? Do you want to detect something at the bottom? Count bubbles or something like that? Or you you want to check for defects?.

As you already mentioned, it's hard because of the reflections, so you could start using less direct light and maybe use a diffuse source. 
No single light bulb, no direct sun, maybe use a white canvas. Or span a thin piece of white cloth between the current light source and the camera.

Comment: My goal is to flatten the image of the bottom of the pot. Something similar to the flattening of a label of a food jar. I am trying to do classification on images of food being cooked, and it is much easier when the angle of the camera does not matter. My ultimate goal is to do this without physical manipulation of a light source. I am open to different approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: Hm, in that case you are probably using YOLO or semantic segmentation or something like that, right? Maybe don't detect the bottom of the pot at all and focus on the "important" things in the image. You will use user supplied images, right? And in most of them the bottom will not even be visible, but covered by the food.

Comment: Thesis or professional application? There are approaches available: https://www.google.com/search?q=food+detection+algorithm